# A reference on Total Variation and its applications in Image Processing

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, image-processing, total-variation

The title is almost self-explanatory; I need a beginners' readable reference (book or article) on total variation and its applications in image processing, know any?
Thanks bunches.

Comment: "Analysis of Variance in Statistical Image Processing" - Kurz and Benteftifa